# Apache common SimplexSolver ObjectiveFunction for maximizing the sum of values in a matrix

Tags: java, apache-commons, linear-programming, apache-commons-math

I am trying to solve the following linear problem by using the Simplex solver from apache-commons: `org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.SimplexSolver`.

[image: http://mathurl.com/ovh582z]

`n` is the number of rows
`m` is the number of columns
`L` is a global limit for the sum value of each row

This is what I have so far:

```java
List<LinearConstraint> constraints = new ArrayList<>();

double[][] A = calculateAValues();
// m = count of columns
// constraint 1: the sum of values in all column must be <= 1
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    double[] v = new double[n];
    for(int j=0; j < n; j++) {
        v[j] = 1;
    }
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(v, Relationship.LEQ, 1));
}
// n = count of rows
// constraint 2: sum of a_i,j in all row must be <= L (Limit)
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    double[] v = new double[m];
    for(int j=0; j < m; j++) {
        v[j] =  A[i][j];
    }
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(v, Relationship.LEQ, L));
}

double[] objectiveCoefficients = new double[n * m];
for(int i = 0; i < n * m; ++i) {
    objectiveCoefficients[i] = 1;
}

LinearObjectiveFunction objective = new LinearObjectiveFunction(objectiveCoefficients, 0);
LinearConstraintSet constraintSet = new LinearConstraintSet(constraints);

SimplexSolver solver = new SimplexSolver();
PointValuePair solution = solver.optimize(objective, constraintSet, GoalType.MAXIMIZE);
return solution.getValue();
```

I have trouble getting the objective function right, and also it might be some other things missing. My every attempt so far resulted in `UnboundedSolutionException`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error seems to be in the coefficient arrays of the linear constraints.

You have `n*m` variables therefore the coefficient arrays for the constraints and the objective functions must have length `n*m`. Unfortunately the `SimplexSolver` silently expands the constraints array if they are shorter than the array of the objective function. So your code did not specify the correct constraints leading to an unbounded solution.

**Constraint 1: the sum of values in all column must be <= 1**

```
for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
{
    double[] v = new double[n*m];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        v[i*n + j] = 1;
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(v, Relationship.LEQ, 1));
}
```

**Constraint 2: sum of a_i,j in all row must be <= L (Limit)**

```
// n = count of rows
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    double[] v = new double[n*m];
    for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
        v[i*n + j] = A[i][j];
    constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(v, Relationship.LEQ, L));
}
```

**Objective coffecifients:**

```
double[] objectiveCoefficients = new double[n * m];
Arrays.fill(objectiveCoefficients, 1.0);
LinearObjectiveFunction objective = LinearObjectiveFunction(objectiveCoefficients, 0);
```

The constraint `x_ij <= 1` is already fulfilled because of constraint 2.
Maybe it makes things more clear to also explicitly specify a constraint for `0 <= x_ij` using a `NonNegativeConstraint`:

```
SimplexSolver solver = new SimplexSolver();
PointValuePair solution = solver.optimize(objective, constraintSet,
     GoalType.MAXIMIZE, new NonNegativeConstraint(true));
```